# I am trying to route to an mvc area and not have to use the folder name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to route to an area without using the folder name.

Example:
mysite.com/Reports/Home/ReportName

I want to use:
mysite.com/Reports/ReportName

I have tried many things in the RegisterRoutes global.asax file and can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please provide the code for when you register the route and the controller method signature?

Comment: In my controller I have many methods that produce reports.  I have posted an example below.  I have also included an example of a route that I have tried.  Basically I want to ignore the folder name in the url.  Under my Reports area and under the Views I have a Home folder that houses all my reports. In the url I want to use something like this..  http://mysite.com/Reports/SalesActivity.  I don't want to have to use the Home folder so I want to create a route that receives it and passes it to the correct action.  Sample code below.

Comment: Simple action method:

        public ActionResult SalesActivity()
        {
            return View("SalesActivity");
        }

Global.asax file:

            routes.MapRoute("Repors_Area", 
                "Reports/{action}", 
                new { area="Reports", controller="Home", action="Index" }, 
                new string [] { "xxxxxxx.Areas.Reports.Controllers" });